# ulimit vs file-max

Tags: limit, ulimit, open-files

Could someone explain limit on open files in linux? The problem is that one of my applications if reporting "Too many open files".

I have

```
ulimit -n
1024
```

but

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
6578523
```

and

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
1536
```

So I already have 1536 > 1024. What is `ulimit -n` then? This is very confusing.

Answer (score 13):

`ulimit` shows the per-process maximum. The two files under `/proc` shows system-wide numbers.

---

From [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/122679/how-do-ulimit-n-and-proc-sys-fs-file-max-differ):

> `file-max` is the maximum File Descriptors (FD) enforced on a kernel level, which cannot be surpassed by all processes without increasing. The `ulimit` is enforced on a process level, which can be less than the `file-max`.

From [http://www.linuxvox.com/post/what-are-file-max-and-file-nr-linux-kernel-parameters/](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222001214/http://www.linuxvox.com/post/what-are-file-max-and-file-nr-linux-kernel-parameters/):

> *What is the `file-max` parameter and what should we tune it to?* The linux documentation definition is that `file-max` denotes the maximum number of filehandles that the Linux kernel will allocate.
>
> [...]
>
> *How do I know if I’m getting close to hitting this limit on my server?* Run the command: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`. This will return three values, denote the number of allocated file handles, the number of allocated but unused file handles, and the maximum number of file handles. Note that `file-nr` IS NOT a tunable parameter. It is informational only. On my server, this returns: `3488 0 793759`.  This means that currently, my server has only allocated 3488 of the 793,759 allocation limit and is in no danger of hitting this limit at this time.

Comment: thanks! which command I can use to estimate by-process fd count to compare with `ulimit -n`?

Comment: @xaxa I imagine that `lsof` would be useful for counting the number of open files for a particular process.