# Can't set ulimit -n like I want to

Tags: linux, ulimit

I just want to set ulimit -n (per process max open files) and for the setting to survive reboots, but it's proving difficult.

I don't know where else to change things to allow it to be set.

```
root@z:~# cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep file-max
fs.file-max = 2000000
root@z:~# cat /etc/security/limits.conf | grep nofile
#        - nofile - max number of open files
* soft     nofile         2000000   
* hard     nofile         2000000
root@z:~# sudo sysctl -p | grep file
fs.file-max = 2000000
root@z:~# ulimit -n 2000000
-su: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
root@z:~# whoami
root
```

strangley this lower setting on the other hand works:

```
ulimit -n 1048576
```

Please let me know how to set per-process limit to 2000000 and for the setting to be maintained across reboots, I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I believe you're probably trying to set ulimit on a remote server, one that have set limits (eg: vps). You cannot change the limit afaik, although you can up it up a bit like you noticed yourself.

Comment: You are confusing system-wide limits with the per-process limits (`ulimit`).  You can't increase the process' limit past the "hard" limit (`ulimit -n -H`), regardless of what the system's limit is.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447583

Comment: @Kusalananda I want to set the per-process limit to be 2000000 and for that to survive reboots. thx. I looked at that other thread, and not a single answer worked for me. After reboots it was always back below 2000000. It is not a vps.

Comment: @Kusalananda, privileged processes can increase the hard limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# ulimit -n 1048576
# ulimit -n 2000000
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
# sysctl fs.nr_open
fs.nr_open = 1048576
# sysctl fs.nr_open=2000000
fs.nr_open = 2000000
# ulimit -n 2000000
# ulimit -n
2000000
```

[proc(5) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html):

> `/proc/sys/fs/nr_open`
> This file imposes a ceiling on the value to which the
> `RLIMIT_NOFILE` resource limit can be raised (see
> getrlimit(2)).  This ceiling is enforced for both
> unprivileged and privileged process.  The default value in
> this file is 1048576.

On the other hand, `file-max` is the limit for all process:

> `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`
> This file defines a system-wide limit on the number of
> open files for all processes.  System calls that fail when
> encountering this limit fail with the error ENFILE.

Not that I have absolutely any idea if sufficiently large numbers of open files cause other problems.

Comment: absolute king. the only thing wrong with this answer is the website won't let me tip you.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this after I struggled with this problem for more than an hour!

1. Delete contents of `/etc/security/limits.d/`
2. Delete `/etc/security/limits.conf` and recreate the file
   like this:

   ```
   vi /etc/security/limits.conf
   root    -   nproc   500000
   root    -   nofile  500000
   myuser  -   nproc   130000
   myuser  -   nofile  130000
   ```

After logout and login, limit was working:

```
ulimit -n
500000
```

Comment: Worked for me, but deleting files wasn't necessary (I simply edited `/etc/security/limits.conf`).